# Getting the schema of the query output in Hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am using Apache Hive to create and execute some queries, but before the query is executed I need to report the structure of the resultset. The queries may involve joins and projections so it will be quite difficult to parse the query. The current solution that we are working on involves parsing the output of explain command but its quite complex itself.

My question is whether there is some simpler way by setting some properties in hive or some query parameters that don't select any data (the map/reduce tasks are not started) but creates a table that I can query via metastore to get the schema?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no simpler way other than using EXPLAIN or DESCRIBE commands to get query schema and table schema.

Answer (score 1):

While not something you can do *before* the query is returned, if you enable

```
set hive.cli.print.header=true;
```

then it will show the schema right before the results.